# OpenTextFile permission denied

Tags: csv, vbscript

I'm creating a .csv file from an .xlsx so I can use it to upload to my CRM from Scribe.  Everything is all fine and dandy but my .xlsx file uses a drop down list in a couple of the columns for 100 rows statically.  So this .csv file has about ~90 rows of ", , , , , , ," which I don't want it to have.  Below is my script that converts this xlsx to csv and then opens the csv back up to remove these rows and re write the .csv file.  The only issue is that I can't re-open the file because I get a permission denied error.

```
Set objArgs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\Users\bmckie\Documents\SugarSync Shared Folders\Janis Jarvis\CRM Import    Spreadsheet"
Set objFolder = objArgs.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile in colFiles
If UCase(objArgs.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "XLSX" Then

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
objExcel.application.visible=false
objExcel.application.displayalerts=false
set objExcelBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objStartFolder & "\" & objFile.Name)

newfile = objStartFolder & "\" & objArgs.GetBaseName(objFile.Name) & ".csv"
objExcelBook.SaveAs newfile, 23

Set objFile = objArgs.OpenTextFile(newfile, 1)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.Readline
    secondLine = strLine
    strLine = Replace(strLine, ",", "")
    strLine = Replace(strLine, " ", "")
    If Len(strLine) > 0 Then
        strNewContents = strNewContents & secondLine & vbCrLf

    End If
Loop
MsgBox(strNewContents)

objFile.Close

Set newobjFile = objArgs.OpenTextFile(newfile, 2)
newobjFile.Write strNewContents
newobjFile.Close
```

Any solutions either in the conversion of .xlsx to .csv or with the permissions issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't open the file to write because excel still has it open. Close the workbook.